# How to assign a default value if current value is nil in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm coming from a heavy javascript background and learning clojure.

In js we can do;

```
var aVariable; //evaluates as falsy
var x = aVariable || 'my Default String';
```

How do you do this in clojure?

Currently I'm reading a header out of a request map coming from compojure.

```
(let [x-forwarded-for (get-in request [:headers "x-forwarded-for"])]
    (println x-forwarded-for)
)
```

In the case where the 'x-forwarded-for' header doesn't exist, the x-forwarded-for value is nil. What's the proper way to test for nil and then reassign x-forwarded-for to another value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Luckily the `get-in` function [has a `not-found` parameter](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/get-in) for exactly this use case:

```
(let [x-forwarded-for (get-in request [:headers "x-forwarded-for"]
                              "default value")]
    (println x-forwarded-for))
```

In general, you could use `or` as @prismofeverything said.

Comment: Actually, using `or` to set fallback values is very idiomatic in the code that I've seen.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the built-in `or`:

```
(let [x-forwarded-for (or (get-in request [:headers "x-forwarded-for"]) "my Default String")]
  (println x-forwarded-for))
```

If the first clause is `nil`, it will use the second.

Comment: This is idiomatic and works well, but be careful around booleans, as `false` will also cause it to fall through (it's unclear from OP's question whether that's desired behavior here).

Answer (score 3):

fnil was designed for this

```
user> ((fnil println "hello") nil)
hello
nil
user> ((fnil println "hello") "world")
world
nil
user> ((fnil println "hello") false)
false
nil
```

Comment: this is pretty cool... more of a specialized case (it is like immediately invoking a utility that was more designed for function currying), but the wider possibilities of actually using this to create a curried function with defaults that only apply within a certain lexical context is really cool